# TypeError: Cannot read property 'ban' of null | Discord.js

Tags: discord, discord.js

**Purpose:** To ban unauthorised users who kick members out of my server.

**Code:**

```
client.on("guildMemberRemove", async member => {

    const FetchingLogs = await member.guild.fetchAuditLogs({
        limit: 1,
        type: "MEMBER_KICK",
    });

    const kickLog = FetchingLogs.entries.first();

    if (!kickLog) {
        return console.log(red(`${member.user.tag} was kicked in ${member.guild.name} but nothing was registered in the audit log...`));
    }

    const { executor, target, createdAt } = kickLog

    if (target.id === member.id) {
        console.log(greenBright(`${member.user.tag} got kicked in ${member.guild.name}, by ${executor.tag}`));
    } else if (target.id === executor.id) {
        return
    }

    if (executor.id !== client.user.id) {
        member.guild.member(executor).ban({
            reason: `Unauthorised Kick`
        }).then(member.guild.owner.send(`**Unauthorised Kick By:** ${executor.tag} \n**Victim:** ${target.tag} \n**Time:** ${createdAt.toDateString()} \n**Sentence:** Ban.`)).catch();
    }

})
```

**Result:** *It bans the executor but it still throws this error:*

```
(node:10272) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'ban' of null
```

Could you please tell me why this is happening and what I could to remove this error. All help appreciated ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is the offending line:

```
member.guild.member(executor).ban(....
```

You supply member.guild.member an executor object and it returns null, then it tries to call the function ban on a null object and you get the error.

Maybe try sending it the executor.id instead, like so:

```
member.guild.member(executor.id).ban
```

Comment: This works and it executes the ban but it still throws this error: 
`(node:1480) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'ban' of null`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ban somebody from a guild you can do this by writing:

```
member.guild.members.ban(executor.id, { reason: "/* Your reason */" })...
```

Sources:

- https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberManager?scrollTo=ban
- and my experience with discord.js

Comment: This works and it executes the ban but it still throws this error: `(node:1480) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'ban' of null`

Comment: Can you provide your new code? Because this shouldn't throw this error

Comment: It's literally what you gave me: ```if (executor.id !== client.user.id) {
        member.guild.member(executor.id).ban({
            reason: `Unauthorised Kick`
        }).then(member.guild.owner.send(`**Unauthorised Kick By:** ${executor.tag} \n**Victim:** ${target.tag} \n**Time:** ${createdAt.toDateString()} \n**Sentence:** Ban.`)).catch();
    }```

Comment: you made the same mistake. `if (executor.id !== client.user.id) { member.guild.**member(executor.id)**.ban({`. i marked it with `*`. You need to change it to: `members.ban(executor.id ...`